# MongoDB / Node.JS: Get sum of field value during a certain year

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I'm currently testing a mongodb database, with **node.js/mongoose**, that follows the schema bellow:

```
{
    "assetID" : Number,
    "dia" : ISODate("year-month-dayT00:00:00Z"),
    "nIncs" : Number,
    "p" : {
            "h0" : [ ],
            "h1" : [ ],
            "h2" : [ ],
              .
              .
              .
            "h23" : [ ]
          }
}
```

I would like to query this database, preferably using aggregation framework, to get the Total sum of "nIncs" for a given year.

**Example:**

```
    {
      "_id" : ObjectId("..."),
      (...)
      "dia" : ISODate("2020-03-18T00:00:00Z"),
      "nIncs" : 1,
    },
    {
      "_id" : ObjectId("..."),
      (...)
      "dia" : ISODate("2020-03-18T00:00:00Z"),
      "nIncs" : 7,
    }

    //OUTPUT: Total sum of "nIncs" for 2020 is 8
```

I did some research here and in the official docs and got to this query

```
Incident.aggregate([ {$group: {_id: {year: {$year: "$dia"}}, total: {$sum: "$nIncs"}}}], function(err, result){
console.log(result);
});
```

but I doesn't output the correct values. Could someone please tell me if there are any changes I have to make to this query in order to achieve a correct output?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: could you add a sample of the output returned from your query?

Comment: What is not correct about the output?  Also remember that all dates are stored in MongoDB in UTC, so you might need to use the form of `$year` that specifies a timezone to make sure Jan 1 and Dec 31 are counted where you expect them to be.